# Cocoa: Snow Leopard fullscreen nsview

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen

Is there any way to turn a nsview in fullscreen in snow leopard ?

Comment: Have you searched the docs? Take a look in NSView class reference. It has a section on full screen mode.

Comment: @rafa Then I'll assume you see the same results I do for "fullscreen" so what have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you -

```
- (IBAction)enterFullScreen:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *fullScreenOptions = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:NSFullScreenModeAllScreens] retain];
    BOOL fullScreenEnteredFlag = [fullScreenView enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:fullScreenOptions];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSView has the following methods

```
– enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:
– exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:
– isInFullScreenMode
```